# Is this hadith true

Tags: hadith

Assalamualykum I heard that there was a hadith that stated on the day of judgement when the muslims will be going in to jannat then 2 of them will be stopped and Allah will say or Allah will send down an angel that will tell one of them to forgive the other but he will say no I will mot forgive him and then Allah will tell them to turn around or Allah will send a angel to tell them to turn around and they will and they will see a beautiful palice and then Allah will tell that person to forgive him for that palice and he will forgive him and then both of them will hold hands and go to jannah.
Is this true

This was the videohttps://youtu.be/GcqP4iMb7Zc
And what book was it u can't find the book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asalaam alaikum

some wordings may differ in various narrations of hadith. i will try to clarify and hope that you would understand it better, insha Allah.

Sayyiduna Anas (radiyallahu ‘anhu) has reported that on the Day of Judgement, there will be two people in front of Allah. One person from them will say: “O Allah, my brother has done injustice to me, so put my sin on his shoulder.
Allah Ta’ala will say to that person: “Lift your head and look inside Jannah [heaven].”
The person will say: “I can see a city of gold and palaces of gold.”
Allah Ta’ala will then say to that person: “If you forgive your brother you can be the owner of that.”

(Mustadrak Hakim, vol. 4 pg. 576)

i believe this is the hadith you are referring to and the muhadhithun have differed regarding the authenticity of this.

Whilst ‘Allamahs Hakim and ‘Azizi (rahimahumallah) have both graded this Hadith as authentic, other Muhaddithun such as ‘Allamahs: Bukhari, Ibn Hibban, Dhahabi, Ibn Hajar, Busiri, and others (rahimahumullah) have graded it as weak, if not very weak.

refference : (Mustadrak Hakim along with Talkhisul Mustadrak, vol. 4 pg. 576, Al-Mughni ‘An Hamlil Asfar, Hadith: 1902, Al-Matalibul ‘Aliyah, Hadith: 4590, Ithaful Khiyarah, Hadith: 7787, Faydhul Qadir, Hadith: 123, Ithafus Sadatil Muttaqin, vol. 6 pgs. 267, vol. 10 pg. 480, and As-Sirajul Munir, vol. 1 pg. 37)

Nonetheless, this Hadith has many supporting narrations and is suitable to quote due to corroboration.

Reference : At-Targhib wat Tarhib, Hadith: 3633, An Nihayah Fil Fitani Wal Malahim, pg. 251, and the footnotes on Al-Matalibul ‘Aliyah, Hadith: 4590; Also see Shaykh Muhammad ‘Awwamah’s footnotes on Tadribur Rawi vol. 2 pg. 382

and there is another very similar beautiful hadith with the same context but due to the lenght of it, i would refrain from quoting it here.please reffer : Faydhul Qadir, Hadith: 123

may Allah the mighty and sublime show you mercy and guide you to the straight path.

Allah knows best.

Comment: JazakAllah for the answer you just made my day happy